# strapi Error connecting to the atlas Mongo database

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, strapi

I want to use mongo atlas with strapi. SO I am reading the values from `.env`

these are the settings

```
connections: {
 default: {
  connector: 'mongoose',
  settings: {
    host: env('DB_MONGO_URL', '127.0.0.1'),
    srv: env.bool('DATABASE_SRV', false),
    port: env.int('DB_PORT', 27017),
    database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'mydb'),
    username: env('DB_USER_NAME', null),
    password: env('DB_PASSWORD', null)
  },
  options: {
    authenticationDatabase: env('AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', null),
    ssl: env.bool('DB_SSL_ENABLE', false),
  },
 },
```

and here are the values

```
DB_MONGO_URL=myproject.random.mongodb.net/mydbt?ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE
DB_USER_NAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=mypasswor
```

but this is showing

```
[2021-10-12T13:18:25.485Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2021-10-12T13:18:25.490Z] error Error connecting to the Mongo database. Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

In network i have allowed, `0.0.0.0` that includes any IP address.

If i pass this url in **MongoDB Compass**

```
mongodb+srv://myproject.random.mongodb.net/mydbt?ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE
```

then this works

I tried the same as well

```
DB_MONGO_URL=mongodb+srv://myproject.random.mongodb.net/mydbt?ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE
DB_USER_NAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

but this shows

```
[2021-10-13T06:59:01.372Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2021-10-13T06:59:01.374Z] error Error connecting to the Mongo database. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb+srv
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

If i tried enable `srv` `true`

```
[2021-10-13T07:01:20.065Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2021-10-13T07:01:20.067Z] error Error connecting to the Mongo database. URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: If you read the first error message it states: `One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted.` Is your IP whitelisted ?

Comment: @dnltinney, yes, i have added 0.0.0.0 and explictely my ip address too , tried both

Comment: Could you try using: `MONGO_CONNECTION_URI="mongodb://myuser:mypassword@myproject.random.mongodb.net/mydbt?ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE"`

Comment: @dnltinney, did not work!!!